# Android Studio Conexão Banco de Dados usando JSON

Tags: php, android, banco-de-dados, json

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou fazendo um app q contém login e registro do usuário e estou usando código em PHP e JSON para isso. Porém verifiquei q meu Response.Listener nunca é chamado, a execução pula ele...
O código que está no Main:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "entrou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Entrou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Erro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
```

E esse é meu RegisterRequest:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "kameo.com.br/control/ayzac_control_signin_mobile.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String email, String name, String nickname, String password, String date, String gender, Response.Listener<String> listener)
{
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("userEmail", email);
    params.put("userName", name);
    params.put("userNickname", nickname);
    params.put("userPassword", password);
    params.put("userBirth", date);
    params.put("userGender", gender);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

Comment: Julgo que esteja a usar Volley. Se assim for tem de adicionar o request ao [RequestQueue](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#simple).

Comment: `RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(email, username, usernick, password, birthdate, gender, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
`
Coloquei o Request Queue

Comment: Implemente o `Response.ErrorListener` para ver se há algum erro.